# Error on if else

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have two fields:

1. Terms (Months) (Numeric)
2. Term (the values are one-off or annual) (Picklist)

How can I display if I choose The Term "one - off", Term (Months) should display one-off, if I choose Annual Subscription Term should display the number of months.

Here is my formula:

```
If (Term__c="Annual subscription", Text(Quote.Term_Months__c),

Term__c="One-off", TEXT(Term__c))
```

I am having error on Term__c="One-off", TEXT(Term__c)) because this is picklist
how can I just say that, if the term is one off just display one-off

[image]

Comment: can you please let me know if both are picklist, and whether we have to show 20 or 18 in a term (Month) if Annual Subscription is Chosen in term field.

Comment: @RamAgarawal: Terms (Months) (Numeric)
Term (the values are one-off or annual) (Picklist)

Comment: If Terms(Months) is Numeric how can you add 'One-off' to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula has two issues:

- You're referencing a picklist field for a direct comparison without using `ISPICKVAL()`
- You have a comparison instead of a value or a second `IF` for your else value.

You can fix it like this:

```
IF (ISPICKVAL(Term__c, "Annual subscription"),
    TEXT(Quote.Term_Months__c), 
    IF(ISPICKVAL(Term__c, "One-off"), 
                 TEXT(Term__c),
                 ""
    )
)
```